# Retrieve a list of deleted Clockify time entry ids

Tags: clockify

We're syncing time entries through to an ERP system via the API, but if a time entry has been deleted in Clockify, we need to remove it from the ERP as well. How can we find deleted time entry ids from Clockify API?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the ERP you are using (and without having ever used ERP myself), it should be trivial to check individual entry IDs in your ERP against Clockify using the "get single time entry" API call. Furthermore, if you enable the Clockify feature that freezes entries after a certain amount of time, you can ensure that you only need to check entries from, say, the past two weeks.